# CSS - Show cards inline on laptop but vertical on mobile

Tags: html, css

## Context and Problem

I am working on [this](https://spotify-mood-ring-2a2e81fbe0b0.herokuapp.com/) page here, focusing on the "Top Artists" bit.

- **Desired Outcome**:

  - From *laptop*: I want cards to be "vertical" rectangle (taller than wider) meaning that the ranking is at the top, then the image is in the middle, then the artist name is at the bottom. Cards share the same width and height, and they are aligned on a horizontal line with "#1" card on the left and "#5" card on the right.
  - From *mobile*: I want the cards to be a "horizontal" rectangle (wider than taller) meaning that ranking is on the left, image is in the middle, and artist name is on the right. I want these cards to share the same width and height.
- **Current Outcome**: Currently, from laptop it seems to be working exactly as I wanted it to (although the title "Top Artists" is on the left rather than on top, for some reason). However, from mobile the cards seem to have all different widths.

## Supporting material

This is what it currently looks like from laptop:

[image]

This is what it currently looks like from mobile:

[image]

## Code

This is what I have in my `<style></style>`

```
.top-artists {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.artist-card {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    flex: 1;
}

.artist-card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.artist-image img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid #1DB954;
}

.artist-info h3 {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
}

.artist-rank {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; 
    color: #1DB954; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.artist-name {
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; 
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-artists-container {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .top-artists {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .artist-card {
        margin: 10px 0; 
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex: 1;
    }
    .artist-image {
        flex: 0 0 100px; 
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .artist-name {
        flex-grow: 1; 
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am creating the cards:

```
<div class="top-artists-container">
    <div class="top-artists" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <h2 class="section-title">Top Artists</h2>
        {% for artist in top_artists %}
        <div class="artist-card">
            <!-- Get the artist image URL from the dictionary using the artist's name as the key -->
            {% set artist_image_url = top_artists_images_by_name.get(artist) %}
            <div class="artist-rank">#{{ loop.index }}</div>
            <div class="artist-image">
                <!-- Use the artist_image_url obtained from the dictionary -->
                <img src="{{ artist_image_url }}" alt="Artist Image">
            </div>
            <div class="artist-name">{{ artist }}</div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

## Trying suggestions from the comments

I tried changing `display: flex;` inside `@media` with `display: block;` as suggested by connexo. The output is not quite what I wanted, here's the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried the suggestion of using `width:100%` in the `@media` and this works decently in the sense that the rectangles are all of the same size, but they are "vertical" and not "horizontal", meaning that the ranking is at the top, the image in the middle, and the artist name at the bottom. Instead, I would like the ranking on the left, the image in the middle, and the artist name on the right. This is what it looks like with `width:100%`:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `.artist-card { display: block; }` instead of `flex`?

Comment: @connexo You mean inside the `@media` or outside?

Comment: Inside `@media`. Play with `margin-left` and `margin-right` to achieve the desired width.

Comment: @connexo I realise I have not made it clear in my post, but in practice the artist names will be of varying length, basically I pull them from the Spotify API, so I don't want to hardcode a size for the cards, but to adjust based on the content. If it makes sense, and if I have understood correctly what you meant (I am new to CSS and HTML)

Comment: @connexo I have tried using `display: block;` and I have put a screenshot in the question to show what it looks after that. The cards still seem to have different widths (and maybe even different heights?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give the cards a fixed width on mobile, you could just add it to the `.artist-card` class in the CSS.

I'd also suggest that you give `.artist-rank` a fixed width on mobile so that it doesn't change size between one-digit and two-digit ranks.

```css
.top-artists {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.artist-card {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    transition: transform 0.2s;
    flex: 1;
}

.artist-card:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.artist-image img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid #1DB954;
}

.artist-info h3 {
    margin: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #333;
}

.artist-rank {
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; 
    color: #1DB954; 
    margin-right: 10px; 
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.artist-name {
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif; 
    color: #000;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-artists-container {
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .top-artists {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .artist-card {
        margin: 10px 0; 
        display: flex; 
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex: 1;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .artist-image {
        flex: 0 0 100px; 
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .artist-name {
        flex-grow: 1; 
        font-size: 18px;
        font-family: 'Gotham', sans-serif;
        color: #000;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
  .artist-rank {
        width: 30px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="top-artists-container">
  <h2 class="section-title">Top Artists</h2>
    <div class="top-artists" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        
      
        <div class="artist-card">
            <!-- Get the artist image URL from the dictionary using the artist's name as the key -->
            
            <div class="artist-rank">#1</div>
            <div class="artist-image">
                <!-- Use the artist_image_url obtained from the dictionary -->
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/400b4f31f95b6eb3d6e58671f29e67b2?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=y&so-version=2" alt="Artist Image">
            </div>
            <div class="artist-name">Great artist</div>
        </div>
        <div class="artist-card">
            <!-- Get the artist image URL from the dictionary using the artist's name as the key -->
            
            <div class="artist-rank">#12</div>
            <div class="artist-image">
                <!-- Use the artist_image_url obtained from the dictionary -->
                <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/400b4f31f95b6eb3d6e58671f29e67b2?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG&f=y&so-version=2" alt="Artist Image">
            </div>
            <div class="artist-name">Good artist</div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The tip for the artist-rank is really good. I've added a screenshot of what it looks like, it's almost there but not quite

Comment: It seems that you have done more changes to the code than I suggested. I have edited my answer to contain a snippet, so you can see, what it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

For using flex you need to add **flex-basis:auto** and **flex:1** together to achieve the full width. Flex:1 is just the portion of an element against other children and does not specifies the basis.

Or You may add **width:100%** to the current code to force fill 100%;

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am a bit of a newby so I need a bit more information. Are you talking about inside `@media` or outside?

Comment: Yes for sure inside the @media. That is the section for mobile view and you used `flex:1` without any `flex-basis`.

Answer (score 1):

You should fit the `width` at *100%* on your cards on your specific `@media`. Like so:

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    // ...
    .artist-card {
        width: 100%;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried this, and it works in the sense that the cards now all have the same size, although they are not in the "horizontal rectangle" sense I mentioned in my question. Meaning that the card shows the ranking at the top, the image in the middle, and the artist name at the bottom. I will add a picture in the question

Answer (score -1):

just do this to parent container.

```
.parent-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
 }
```

Learn more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat